USB interrupt EP transfer
It is basic USB protocol question. Consider having interrupt IN EP, declaring its bInterval to be 10ms. As far as I understood, by accepting particular configuration, host will oblige itself to be able to initiate IN transactions for this EP at least once in 10ms (if needed) to collect data it needs to deliver.
My question is how host can "promise" the time frame for that EP, without knowing what amount of data it needs to transfer every 10ms ?
